# increment serial no of row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a code to dynamically generate rows.
I am having a trouble that the row no is wrongly generated. The problem comes that the row which is firstly visible's serial no is changed and others just move down with correct format.Please anybody tell what should I do to get Serial no correctly Following is my code. 
html code

```js
    var counter = 1;
    $(function () {

    $("#button1").click(function () {
        counter++;
        $('#dynamic').append($("#main-row").clone().attr("id", counter + 1));
        $("#serial").text(counter);

    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="dynamic">
              <div class="row " id="main-row">
               <div class="col-sm-1 serial  " id="serial">1</div>
                   <div class="col-sm-2  ">
                    <select class="container-fluid" name="select item"        id="selection">
                    
                    <option>Please select item</option>
                        <option value="30000" id="30000">Computer</option>
                        <option value="4000" id="4000">Mobile</option>
                        <option value="5000" id="5000">LCD</option>
                        <option value="1500" id="1500">Keyboard</option>
                        <option value="500" id="500">Mouse</option>
                    
                     </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length quantity" type="number" min="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" required/></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length price " type="number" name="unitPrice"  id="price1" value="" min="1" readonly/></div>  
            <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="length total" type="number" name="total" min="1" id="total"  readonly/></div>
            <button class="btn-primary col-sm-1 del ">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical offset-10">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Add Row</button>
        <button class="btn-warning" id="btnSubmit">Submit Order</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the id as a unique attribute value. When you clone a content, all `ids` inside that content would be duplicated. So, you wouldn't have unique `ids`.

I changed your code and used `classes` instead of `ids`

```js
var counter = 1;
    $(function () {

    $("#button1").click(function () {
        counter++;
        $('#dynamic').append($(".main-row:first").clone().attr("id", "row_" + counter));
        $("#row_" + counter).find(".serial").text(counter);

    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="dynamic">
              <div class="row main-row">
               <div class="col-sm-1 serial">1</div>
                   <div class="col-sm-2  ">
                    <select class="container-fluid" name="select item"        id="selection">
                    
                    <option>Please select item</option>
                        <option value="30000">Computer</option>
                        <option value="4000">Mobile</option>
                        <option value="5000">LCD</option>
                        <option value="1500">Keyboard</option>
                        <option value="500">Mouse</option>
                    
                     </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length quantity" type="number" min="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" required/></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length price " type="number" name="unitPrice"  id="price1" value="" min="1" readonly/></div>  
            <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="length total" type="number" name="total" min="1" id="total"  readonly/></div>
            <button class="btn-primary col-sm-1 del ">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical offset-10">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Add Row</button>
        <button class="btn-warning" id="btnSubmit">Submit Order</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Ahmad, I'm glad hearing that. By the way, you still have some elements with `id` inside the cloned content. I strongly recommend you make them nummerized. Or, use `class` instead

Comment: ok Thanks I will surely look deep into it. Thanks for your help. I am just a beginner so I made such type of mistakes. But I will learn from my mistakes surely

Comment: Hey bro @Mojtaba are you here? I have one more question in this?

Comment: @Ahmad, I have to run. please put your question. I will reply in 4 hours

Comment: I wanted to ask that if I delete the row then the sequence of serials get disturbed. Can you tell the function which i should implement to rearrange serials whenever i press delete button to delete the row?

Comment: @Ahmad this is not what someone can explain in the comments. You can create another topic for that. By the way, I'm pretty sure if you do a search, you would find the answer quickly. But, if you couldn't, post a question

Comment: Thanks I will do research

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS counters for this.

Check the following code snippet:

```js
var counter = 1;
$(function() {

  $("#button1").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $('#dynamic').append($("#main-row").clone().attr("id", counter + 1));


  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  counter-reset: row;
  /* Set the row counter to 0 */
}

.container .row::before {
  counter-increment: row;
  /* Increment the row counter*/
  content: counter(row) ": ";
  /* Display the row */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="dynamic">
  <div class="row " id="main-row">

    <div class="col-sm-2  ">
      <select class="container-fluid" name="select item" id="selection">
                    
                    <option>Please select item</option>
                        <option value="30000" id="30000">Computer</option>
                        <option value="4000" id="4000">Mobile</option>
                        <option value="5000" id="5000">LCD</option>
                        <option value="1500" id="1500">Keyboard</option>
                        <option value="500" id="500">Mouse</option>
                    
                     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length quantity" type="number" min="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" required/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length price " type="number" name="unitPrice" id="price1" value="" min="1" readonly/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="length total" type="number" name="total" min="1" id="total" readonly/></div>
    <button class="btn-primary col-sm-1 del ">Delete</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical offset-10">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Add Row</button>
  <button class="btn-warning" id="btnSubmit">Submit Order</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increment counter on the basis of row appended to container.After using this logic your code will as like below.

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
        var counter = $(".container>.row").length;
        var next_id = counter + 1;
        $('#dynamic').append($("#main-row").clone().attr("id", next_id));
        $("#"+next_id).find(".serial").text(next_id);
});
```